# Kotlin one-liners with mismatched return types

Tags: kotlin

I am using an anonymous object in a section of code that I'm writing in Kotlin.  The overridden method can be condensed into a one-liner because it's one line of code, but the one-liner method call actually returns a value of type `T`.

```
override onSomeListenerEvent(index: Int): Unit = myArrayList.remove(index)
```

What's the best way to keep this a one-liner?

Answer (score 1):

You could create an extension to change any type to unit:

```
fun Any?.discardResponse() = Unit
```

Then:

```
override fun onSomeListenerEvent(index: Int) = myArrayList.remove(index).discardResponse()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work, even if `onSomeListenerEvent` has specified `T` as return type:

```
override fun onSomeListenerEvent(index: Int) { myArrayList.remove(index) }
```

If you rather wanted to ask how you can keep your `=`-assignment, then the following will also work (but as the first is shorter and does not require the `apply` I would stick to the first):

```
override fun onSomeListenerEvent(index: Int) = Unit.apply { myArrayList.remove(index) }
```

But then again: your current solution is already easy enough and does not take any inconvenient route. So either use: `: Unit` or the curly brackets ;-)

Comment: The first line won't survive code-formatting with simple blocks and newlines

Comment: The second neither... If you want that, you need to have an extension function in place... as also s1m0nw1 also has shown... but I really do not understand what's the benefit of a one-liner here... I think the first just clearly shows that nothing is returned, but the method is doing something... adding something like `toUnit` or `discardResponse()` just makes it longer and it isn't even "standard" so you first need to lookup what that does exactly... I am not sure whether that's a good idea...

Comment: Exactly, youre right.  I'm not asking for the sake of just doing anything that works, but if there's a good way, it'd be nice to use it

Comment: that's fine :-) just wanted to be clear about it ;-)

Comment: "as Unit" might also be an option

Comment: true... still I think the main recommendation (either use `: Unit` or the curly brackets) holds ;-) all the other stuff doesn't really make the code more readable and some even execute/create code that doesn't contain any real logic (e.g. `Unit.apply`) ;-)